# Find the longest non-contiguous subarray that the absolute difference of each adjacent pair in it is <= 1

Tags: arrays, sorting

Hi I'm new to programming, and here's a sibling question that I came up originally from this
HackerRank problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/three-month-preparation-kit-picking-numbers/problem) and I haven't figured out a way yet, anyone has any idea please ?

Upgraded Question: "Find the length of the longest subarray, subArr,  from an integer array such that the abosolute difference of each adjacent pair in subArr is less than or equal to 1. The subarray doesn't need to be contiguous. Array sequence matters. "

Input: 4 6 5 3 3 1

Output: 3  , because (4 _ _ 3 3 _)

Input: 4 6 5 3 2 1

Output: 4 , because (4 _ _ 3 2 1)

Input: 1 2 2 3 4 5

Output: 6, because all elements satisfy the condition.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here's the code I have for the HackerRank problem:                                                                             public static int pickingNumbers(List<Integer> a) {
    // Write your code here
        int[] freq = new int[100];
        int count = 0;
        for (Integer i: a){
            int k = i.intValue();
            freq[k]++;
        } 
        for (int i=1; i<freq.length-1; i++){
            int temp = freq[i]+freq[i+1];
            if (count<temp){
                count = temp;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }